# Android executeSQL not working (INSERT INTO TABLE2 SELECT * FROM TABLE1)

Tags: android, sqlite

I've to move datas to one table to another.
The new table will be as the old one but without a constraint (on conflict replace) so the columns are the same.

This is the query I've to do: `INSERT INTO TABLE2 SELECT * FROM TABLE1`

I've got a big problem because I think that I cannot execute this kind of query with:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + Tables.TRACKS + "_2  SELECT * FROM " + Tables.TRACKS );
```

execSQL fails with this error ( db onUpgrade ):

```
06-04 12:25:50.000: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(17817): Registering sqlite logging func: /data/data/com.musixmatch.android.lyrify/databases/library.db
06-04 12:25:50.000: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(17817): DB info: open db, path = /data/data/com.musixmatch.android.lyrify/databases , key = lafvYvq, flag = 6, file size = 101376
06-04 12:25:50.000: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(17817): DB info: path = /data/data/com.musixmatch.android.lyrify/databases , key = lafvYvq, handle: 0x1bd8bd8, type: w, r/w: (0,1), mode: delete, disk free size: 1243 M


06-04 12:25:50.010: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(17817): DB info: close db, path = /data/data/com.musixmatch.android.lyrify/databases , key = lafvYvq, handle = 0x1bd8bd8, type = w, r/w = (0, 0)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817): Couldn't open library.db for writing (will try read-only):
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:95)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:2008)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1948)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at com.designfuture.music.provider.MusicDatabase.alterTrackFragmentForFileIDSupport(MusicDatabase.java:316)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at com.designfuture.music.provider.MusicDatabase.onUpgrade(MusicDatabase.java:242)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:249)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at com.designfuture.music.provider.MusicProvider.query(MusicProvider.java:199)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:94)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
06-04 12:25:50.030: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(17817):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
06-04 12:25:50.030: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(17817): DB info: open db, path = /data/data/com.musixmatch.android.lyrify/databases , key = lafvYvq, flag = 1, file size = 101376
06-04 12:25:50.030: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(17817): DB info: path = /data/data/com.musixmatch.android.lyrify/databases , key = lafvYvq, handle: 0x1bec760, type: r, r/w: (1,0), mode: delete, disk free size: 1243 M
06-04 12:25:50.030: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(17817): DB info: close db, path = /data/data/com.musixmatch.android.lyrify/databases , key = lafvYvq, handle = 0x1bec760, type = r, r/w = (0, 0)
06-04 12:25:50.040: W/AsyncQuery(17817): Exception thrown during handling EVENT_ARG_QUERY
06-04 12:25:50.040: W/AsyncQuery(17817): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 7 to 9: /data/data/com.musixmatch.android.lyrify/databases/library.db
06-04 12:25:50.040: W/AsyncQuery(17817):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:262)
06-04 12:25:50.040: W/AsyncQuery(17817):    at com.designfuture.music.provider.MusicProvider.query(MusicProvider.java:199)
06-04 12:25:50.040: W/AsyncQuery(17817):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
06-04 12:25:50.040: W/AsyncQuery(17817):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
06-04 12:25:50.040: W/AsyncQuery(17817):    at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:94)
06-04 12:25:50.040: W/AsyncQuery(17817):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 12:25:50.040: W/AsyncQuery(17817):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
06-04 12:25:50.040: W/AsyncQuery(17817):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I think that it's because I've a SELECT into the query.. this is from the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL
>   statement that returns data.

If I use

```
db.rawQuery( "INSERT INTO " + Tables.TRACKS + "_2  SELECT * FROM " + Tables.TRACKS, null  );
```

It execute without error but it doens't do anything. I think that's because rawQuery is used to do SELECT queries and wont write into the database.

**UPDATE**: If I select all records with a normal query, then with a loop I insert them into the new table everything works but this is not the optimized way and I don't want to have a slow upgrading app

**UPDATE2**:

These are the only differences between those 2 tablers:

new table has 3 new string column and they CAN be null
new table wont have a unique ( ON CONFLICT REPLACE ) constraint that the old table has

both tables have this field: `BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"`. Have I to exclude that field from the insert? Also remember that the second tablet is empty at the upgrade time (I'm creating it on the upgrade moment)

So what have I to do to execute a query that need to write and read at the same time as mine?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the error that you are getting?

Comment: Updated the initial post

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` statements you used to create your two tables with? You are getting a constraint-violation when inserting. Also, `db.rawQuery("INSERT ..` isn't going to do *anything* - **always** use `execSQL` for insert, updates and deletes.

Comment: New table has 3 new field (they can be null) and it wont have a unique constraint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not posting the table layouts, let's start with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
   _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   value1 TEXT,
   value2 TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (
   _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   value2 TEXT,
   value1 TEXT,
   value3 TEXT,
   value4 TEXT,
   value5 TEXT
);
```

To correctly insert values from `TABLE1` into `TABLE2` you must consider that order & column count is **important** & must match (& if you have primary keys it's always a good idea to omit them from the insert & select statements - don't go around copying stuff like that).

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (value1, value2) SELECT value1, value2 FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: So the best way is also to not omit columns to select and the order of the insert. I'll give a try after launch and I'll answer you back :)

Comment: Unless the tables are exactly the same (in that case - why copy?) you should always specify your INSERT & SELECT columns to match each other.

Comment: I want to remove that ON CONFLICT REPLACE and sqlite3 wont allow you to alter the table to remove that constraint. So the only way to do that is to create a new table, move data, delete old one, rename the new one to the old one's name.